# Display records based on same id but remove the similarity on sql

Tags: php, sql, odbc

maybe the subject is duplicate or have the similarity with others, but i haven't found what i'm looking for.

I have a `Sales Order` table on sql, and I am using **odbc** to connect

`id_sales_order   date         customer    product    qty
        001       2017-12-12   ABC         laptop      1
        001       2017-12-12   ABC         printer     1
        001       2017-12-12   ABC         mouse       2
        002       2017-12-15   Hercules    pc          1
        002       2017-12-15   Hercules    hdd         1`

and I have a code

```
<body>
<?php
$konek = odbc_connect("otosurabaya","mike","mike") or die("Error Connect to Database");
$sql = "SELECT id_sales_order, customer, product, date,qty FROM Kreasi_Cabang.dbo.QNota_SalesOrder where sales='" .$_SESSION['username']. "' group by id_sales_order, customer, product, date, qty" ;

$hasil = odbc_exec($konek, $sql) or die ("Error Execute [".$sql."]");
$noUrut = 1;
?>
<?php

while($result = odbc_fetch_array($hasil))
{
?>

<div class="panel panel-success">
<div class="panel-heading" >
<h3 class="panel-title" align="center"><strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> </strong>  </h3> 
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">

<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
<th width="131" scope="row">Customer</th>
<td width="44">:</td>
<td width="800" align="left"><?php echo $result['customer'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">SO ID</th>
<td>:</td>
<td align="left"><?php echo $result['id_sales_order'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Date
<td align="left"><?php echo $result['date'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th height="49" scope="row">Product</th>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left">QTY</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row"><?php echo $result['product'];?></th>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left"><?php echo $result['qty'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php   }?>

</table>


</p>


</div>
<hr />
<?php
odbc_close($konek);
?>
</body>
```

The above code, it display record only per row, I want to remove the same value and keep the others.

I have search and try many syntax, please need your expertise

I want to display the record as below

```
Customer : ABC 
Date     : 2017-12-12
ID SO    : 001
Product    QTY
Laptop      1
Printer     1
Mouse       1
```

Comment: so you want to do a groupby?

Comment: Just put `DISTINCT` before the column name that you want to be unique.

Comment: yes, i want do a group by – madalinivascu

Comment: is DISTINCT can provide that?  mohessaid

Comment: you want result as you provide for each customer. Am i Right ?

Comment: No, it won't, I thought you are trying to get a list of customers (unique without duplications) or products. But as I reread your question, I think you are looking for a way to get all the orders by the same customer merged or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the if condition inside the while loop. And need to put the flag so that your customer name and other details should be print once and uniquely.

And  product details will be print multiple times. Here is the code for that:

```
<?php

$customer_name = '';
$sale_date = '';
$sales_id = '';
$flag = true;
?>

<div class="panel panel-success">
<div class="panel-heading" >
<h3 class="panel-title" align="center"><strong> <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> </strong>  </h3> 
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">

<table width="100%" border="1">
<?php
while($result = odbc_fetch_array($hasil))
{
?>

<?php if($customer_name != $result['customer'] && $sale_date !=  $result['date'] && $sales_id != $result['id_sales_order']) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th width="131" scope="row">Customer</th>
        <td width="44">:</td>
        <td width="800" align="left"><?php echo $result['customer'];?></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">SO ID</th>
        <td>:</td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $result['id_sales_order'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Date
        <td align="left"><?php echo $result['date'];?></td>
    </tr>

<?php 
    $customer_name = $result['customer'];
    $sale_date =  $result['date'];
    $sales_id = $result['id_sales_order'];
    $flag = true;
} else { $flag = false; } 
    if($flag) {
?>  
    <tr>
        <th height="49" scope="row">Product</th>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left">QTY</td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $result['product'];?></th>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $result['qty'];?></td>
    </tr>

<?php   } ?>
```

You can change in the if condition `&&` with `||` if you want to print the customer details in case of any detail is not matching. Like if date is different or if sales id is different.

**Note:** I put the if condition on the basis of your data shown in question. you can change it as per your requirement.

Comment: @Mahdee My pleasure to help you :)